# How can i get the url that raised the AssociationUriMapper in WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using the guide at [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to launch my application on a given file-name extension.

The problem is that the uri contains response of kind `/FileTypeAssociation?fileToken=17B9F681-058D-4B01-B33F-FAFF70760D25` and i cannot get the actual http path that originated this event.

So, how can i get the HTTP URL that raised this event in my application?
The user actually clicked on a URL which i am not able to read. How can accomblish that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with the current SDK. You only get the protocol that your app was launched with (e.g: `/FileTypeAssociation?fileToken=17B9F681-058D-4B01-B33F-FAFF70760D25`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the original location, but you can copy the file into your local storage using [SharedStorageAccessManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.storage.sharedaccess.sharedstorageaccessmanager.aspx). If you want apps to send you URLs, then you should look into the [Share Contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871373.aspx)